# Elastic Search IndexCreationException

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a new index in Elastic Search as follows

```
  PUT /abtest2
    {
      "settings":{

       "analysis":{

         "char_filter":{

           "replaceJunk":{

             "type":"pattern_replace",
             "pattern":"[^\\d+]",
             "replacement":""
           }
         },

          "analyzer":{

     "dateAnalyzer":{

     "type":"custom",
     "tokenizer":"standard",
     "char_filter":["replaceJunk"]
     }
    }

   }
  },

      "mappings":{

            "fix":{

                "properties": {

                   "Date": {
                      "type": "date",
                      "analyzer": "dateAnalyzer"
                   }
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

so basically, i want to create a custom analyzer for my Date field which might have some non numeric characters coming in. Now, i try to pass a value like

```
PUT /abtest2/fix/5
{
     "Date":"14186196000-0005"
}
```

but this gives me an error

```
    {
   "error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse [Date]]; nested: MapperParsingException[failed to parse date field [14186196000-0005], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"14186196000-0005\" is malformed at \"00-0005\"]; ",
   "status": 400
}
```

shouldn't this field have been analyzed and transformed ?

please advise

Comment: Should be `[^\\d]+` probably.

Comment: nope, still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch doesn't allow analysers to be specified for date fields, just for strings. If you try `curl http://localhost:9200/abtest2/_mapping` after applying your settings, you will see:

```
{
   "abtest2": {
      "mappings": {
         "fix": {
            "properties": {
               "Date": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The analyser has been removed and isn't being used.

You will need to clean up your data before sending it to ES in order for it to be parsed correctly as a date.

Comment: thanks Matt, but even if i change it to string, it still does not remove the - character

Comment: even if i set the pattern to be just -

"replaceJunk":{
         
         "type":"pattern_replace",
         "pattern":"-",
         "replacement":""
       }

Comment: What you will find is that the hyphen is being removed during indexing and querying, although it still appears in the field when displayed. If you check your analyzer, you can see the generated token:
`curl http://localhost:9200/abtest2/_analyze?analyzer=dateAnalyzer\&pretty -d "14186196000-0005"`